# Htaccess Not Working - Redirect 301

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Due to some bad URLs, we generated some links that don't work and I want to redirect them with a 301 redirect to clear up some webmaster tools issues with Google.

So, we have this URL like this:

```
http://www.site.com/subdomain/z//-products
```

*Note that subdomain is variable, the rest of the url is static.

As a side note, this URL makes no sense, that's why I want to redirect it.  It should be something like this:

```
http://www.site.com/bedroom/z/12345/bedroom-furniture-products
```

Anyway, we had these bad URLs being dynamically generated.  We've fixed them, but google picked them up and keeps trying to crawl them.  I want to create an htaccess rule to 301 redirect them and the issue should wash out eventually.

Here's what I tried with htaccess to no avail:

```
^(.*)/n//-products/?$ $1 [R=301,B]
```

I've also tried all kinds of permutations of this and it's not working.  I suspected it was an entity escaping issue, but my research led me to add the [B], but that didn't seem to work either.  It's like the redirect rule is working, but it's just redirecting to the original page.

What am i missing here?

Comment: Obviously from this bad URL `/subdomain/z//-products` we can't redirect to `/bedroom/z/12345/bedroom-furniture-products`. So you have to specify your requirement, i.e. to which URI you exactly want to redirect to for the bad URLs?

Comment: Yes, you are correct.  All I want to do is redirect this:  /subdomain/z//-products to /subdomain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe anubhava is correct, in that there is inconsistency between the sample URL you describe `/subdomain/z//-products` and the RewriteRule you attempted to apply. Not sure if this is a typo or not. It may even be the case your copy/paste operation actually added the "/n" literally.

Anyhoo, let us presume that you want to make the rule work with `/subdomain/z//-products`:

```
RewriteRule ^/([^/]+)/z//\-products/?$ http://www.site.com/$1 [R=301]
```

See [the example 1 slides of this  PDF](http://people.apache.org/~rbowen/presentations/apacheconUS2009/mod_rewrite.pdf) to get the quick first portion. It is much faster than using `(.*)`.

We literally match the `z` character and the surrounding slashes. We escape the `-` character, then we do the rest of the URL and optionally match the trailing slash. We use, if memory serves correctly, an "external" style redirect so that the robots re-open a separate HTTP connection, appending the matched backreference, and hand off the status code.

Let me know if that works.

Comment: Thank, I will try this.  Is it the dash that's causing the rule to bug out?

Comment: Yes, I believe so. I always escape characters that might foul the pattern up. You are literally looking for a "-" character in the URL, but since you are using PCRE regex parser of in Apache, the "-" has significance since it can be searched for literally, or used to specify a range. For example: `[a-zA-Z]` specifies a character class of all lowercase and all upper case letters. I think putting the "-" in without escaping broke it all. I personally use a Mac OS X app called `Patterns` to help me out. It will even spit out the regex in the programming language of your choice's format.

Answer (score 0):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^subdomain/z/-products/?$ /$1 [L,R=302,NC]
```

Once you verify it is working fine, replace `R=302` to `R=301`. Avoid using `R=301` (Permanent Redirect) while testing your mod_rewrite rules.